# Create routee actor on demand

Tags: akka, akka.net, akka-persistence

How do I configure a **router resizer strategy which only creates a new incarnation of a routee on demand** (i.e. when I *tell* a message to the router) and stops the routees when their mailbox is empty (i.e. when the actor is idle)?

The behaviour of the DefaultResizer is to create all the routee actors upfront, but I'd rather have them be created when necessary. I still want to use a router because this means I can set an upper limit on the number of routees created.

I would expect the following to work, but it won't create new actors. I've set a default number of `RoundRobinPool` instances to 0, using a `DefaultResizer` range of 0 to 5, and `messagesPerResize` of 1 to trigger a resize on each request:

```
var props = Props
    .Create<MyRouteeActor>()
    .WithRouter(new RoundRobinPool(0).WithResizer(new DefaultResizer(0, 5, messagesPerResize: 1)));
```